# Display of List Webpart on Intranet Page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, web-part, list-view, content-query-web-part

Experts,

I`ve created a List using SPD2013 and its working fine.
Added the list as a standard CQWP webpart to the intranet page to show the list items on the Intranet homepage.

However, I want the content to be viewed in a much richer format.
Example: Column1 - (Column2) - Column3

But it show by defaul in standard format as:
Column1 Column2 Column 3

How to get: hypens & bracket as shown in the above example.

Comment: Do you want the column titles to be like that or do you want 1 column displaying the information like that?

Comment: HI Roland,
Not sure what u asking.

Column name is correct and I want to display information from 3 columns

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CQWP to display list items then you can manage the view and look and feel of your list items in any of the manner which you want. You have full access to work with look and feel of List item in CQWP using SPD.

Please have a look to this link [Customizing the Content Query Web Part and Item Style](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756834/Customizing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-and-Item-St)

Or if you want to read full article on this topic then you find here [How to: Customize XSL for the SharePoint Content By Query Web Part (ECM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb447557%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Let me know whether it helped.

Thanks